# NodeJS module include function

Tags: node.js

In order to allow customization / localization of a standard nodejs application, I need to allow for a custom .js file to override / re-declare a standard .js file.

#### myfunc.js

```
module.exports = {
    include:include
}

function include(file_) {
    with (global) {
        eval(fs.readFileSync(file_) + '');
    };
};
```

#### custom.index.js

```
var x = require('../somefile');
exports.index = function(){
  myvar:'yyyyyy'
}
```

#### index.js

```
var x = require('../somefile');
exports.index = function(){
  myvar:'xxxxxx'
}
var fn = require('myfunc');
fn.include('custom.index.js');
```

The problem appears to be, that the evaluated code is included into the myfunc.js file and not into the calling file index.js, and any relative paths to require() files are relative to the index.js file and not the calling file, resulting in a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this.  A mistake in `custom.myother.js` will result in difficult-to-debug errors (not to mention if you accidentally run your code with `--use-strict` everything will stop working)

Instead, load the other code as a module and merge it with a default one:

#### myCustomLocalizationEngine.js

```
var defaults = {
  name: "Cool Application",
  fun1: function() { console.log(this.name); }
};

var extend = require("underscore").extend;

module.exports.load = function load(file_) {
  var customizations = require(file_);
  return extend({}, defaults, customizations);
};
```

#### customization.magic.js

```
module.exports.name = "De Moda Aplicación";
```

#### Some dependent script

```
var i118n = require('myCustomLocalizationEngine');
var bundleES = i118n.load('customization.magic.js'),
    bundleUS = i118n.load();

bundleES.fun1();  // Logs "De Moda Aplicación"
bundleUS.fun1(); // Logs "Cool Application"
```

If you absolutely, positively, for-the-good-of-all-that-is-holy-please-tell-me-so-that-I-can-save-all-mankind-from-the-creatures-of-absolute-evil must do this then:

<sup>Abandon Hope, All Ye Who Enter Here</sup>

> pass in `global` and `__dirname` to your `include` function `function include(g, directory, filename) { with(g) { eval(fs.readFileSync(path.join(directory, filename)) + ''); }; }` e. g. `fn.include(global, __dirname, 'custom.myother.js')`

Comment: Thanks, once I understood how to use the underscore extend, I managed to get your solution working.